# AttributeError at /BRMapp/view-books/

Tags: django

**I am developing Book Record Management system as my first project on django but after performing all my functionalities I got a problem in my views.py file in a function name view-book in a line(books=models.Book.objects.all()).Although i have made a class name 'Book' in models.py and i also have imported models in my views.py file with a line(form django.db import models).Although it is not working.Kindly help
Error showing like this:::**

```
module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Book'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/BRMapp/view-books/
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Book'
Exception Location: G:\Django projects\firstproject\BRMapp\views.py, line 41, in viewBooks
Python Executable:  C:\Users\amann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.2
Python Path:    
['G:\\Django projects\\firstproject',
 'C:\\Users\\amann\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\amann\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\amann\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\amann\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\amann\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\amann\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 12 Aug 2021 10:19:08 +0000
```

Comment: You're going to have to show some code. Please format it correctly when you add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception `models` points to the `models` submodule of the `django.db` module, but there is no `Book` defined in that module.

Likely the `Book` originates from elsewhere, from an `appname.models` module.

You thus import this with:

```
from appname.models import Book

# …

def viewBooks(request):
    # …
    #        ↓ no models.
    books = Book.objects.all()
    # …
```

Comment: @AmanNepali: please edit the question with the current state of your `viewBooks` view together with the *full* traceback...

Comment: @AmanNepali: there is no view in `views.py` with the name `Book`?